# Context free grammar for the language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I had to make a context free grammar for the following language:
$$
\{a^m b^n \mid 1 \le m \le n \le 2m\}
$$

What I thought is:
\begin{align*}
S &\to aXbb \\
X &\to a|aab|abb|ab|E
\end{align*}

Is this correct way of writing a CFG?

Comment: Your grammar allows only five words: aabb, aaabbb, aabbb, aabbb, abb. Note that, in addition to missing longer words, you are also missing the short word ab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CFG should be $$S\rightarrow aSb|aSbb|ab|abb$$
where $S$ is the start symbol.
So for example if you have to produce the word $a^mb^n$ then as we know $m\leq n\leq 2m$ then you will use $2n-m$ times this production ($S \rightarrow aSb$) and $m-n$ times this production ($S \rightarrow aSbb$).
hence you will get  $(2n-m)+(m-n) \times a$ and $(2n-m)+2(m-n)\times b$ which is desired.

Again if $m\leq n\leq km$ then 
CFG would be 
$$S\rightarrow aSb|aSbb|.....|aS\underbrace{bb....b}_{\text{k times}}|ab|abb|......|a\underbrace{bb....b}_{\text{k times}}$$
and here also logic is same.

Comment: There's a small oversight: the empty string is a word in your grammar.

Comment: yes the empty string cannot be there. so that needs to be taken care of.

Comment: We could modify it to be S -> aAb and A-> aAb, aAbb and empty string

Comment: @Richia: the underlying idea will work, but don't forget that `abb` is in your grammar....

Comment: @RichaSachdev if you are talking about this $$S\rightarrow aAb \\ A\rightarrow aAb|aAbb|\epsilon$$ then how will you produce $abb$ which is in the language

Comment: @RichaSachdev well you can do $S \rightarrow aAB|aAbb$ and else is same
But if written in short it will be the same as I have written in my answer

Comment: @SaurabhHota: But I cannot include empty string so I can include in my definition A in addition to all also just goes to b. Then I can have abb. Do you think the definition is complete now

Comment: @RichaSachdev yes now your grammar is complete and sound.

Comment: I think that there is a simpler grammar: $S\rightarrow aSbV|\epsilon $ $V\rightarrow b|\epsilon $

Answer (score 5):

It's interesting to see so many different ideas. My own hint is that we can produce words by "creating" `a`s and `b`s iteratively, and each step we can do one of two things: create one `a` and one `b`, or create one `a` and two `b`s.

(be aware that each answer so far is leading towards a different presentation of the grammar: you can't combine the hints directly, and should probably only think about one at a time)

Comment: Well, I don't see how this is different. You may render the grammar in different ways, but the idea is the same: with every $a$ you generate one or two $b$s; only you decide on this right away, Ayman delays the substitution $B \to b$ for later, and my solution forces the order in some particular way (the multiplication of $b$s is commutative after all). For me it is exactly the same. +1 for the comment in parentheses -- I can imagine that one could easily miss that.

Comment: The actual execution of our three answers are different, and I get the vague impression that we went through very different thought processes to arrive at our answer. It looks like you had a very algebraic approach to the problem. When I read Ayman's, I get a vague impression of a general technique of inserting intermediate symbols to allow and constrain further choices in a construction. Neither idea crossed my mind when I looked at the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's not correct. Consider the word $a^4b^5$. This word belongs to the language because $m=4$, $n=5$ and $1 \le 4 \le 5 \le 2 \times 4$. However, your grammer cannot produce it, as it can produce three "$a$"s at most.

Here is a hint: Make $S$ produce one $a$, one $b$ and one $B$ recursively. Make $B$ produce one $b$ at most. This ensures that $1 \le m \le n$, and $n \le 2m$.

Comment: I can have this.

Comment: Whats if I change to S-> S1 S2 and S1-> ab S2-> aXbb and X-> aX|aaXb|aXbb|aXb|E. Will this be too long?

Comment: Among the words that grammar produces are ababb and abaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabb.

Comment: @RichaSachdev - Still incorrect, I'm afraid. This grammar can generate the word $ababb$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** 
$$a^m b^n = a^{2m-n}a^{n-m}(bb)^{n-m}b^{2m-n}$$